# When trying to turn my pyc file back into a py file using uncompyle6.exe I am running into an error

Tags: python, parsing, pyinstaller, pyc

I am trying to run this command

`uncompyle6.exe -o .\decompile\ .\unpacked\app.exe\app.pyc`

So that I can reverse the app.pyc file into app.py. However I am getting this error.

```
Instruction context:

 L. 356        10  LOAD_FAST                'self'
                  12  LOAD_METHOD              checkUserKey
                  14  CALL_METHOD_0         0  '0 positional arguments'
                  16  POP_TOP
                  18  JUMP_FORWARD         20  'to 20'
->              20_0  COME_FROM            18  '18'

# file .\unpacked\app.exe\app.pyc
# Deparsing stopped due to parse error
.\unpacked\app.exe\app.pyc --
# decompile failed
```

I am not sure why it is not working. I have searched for a solution but couldn't find one.